# jQuery load() function not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables, parameter-passing

Any idea why this code:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.friend' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    overlayerOn();
    var $uid = $(this).attr("href");
    var $br = $('#board');
    $br.css('display', 'block');
    $('#board').load("messages.php?uid=" + $uid);
});
```

Is not sending anything in ...php?uid= ?

here is php script(but so far there is nothing just trying to receive the variable):

```
$id = $_REQUEST['uid'];

echo "<div id='hovno'>" . $id . "</div>";
```

And every time I receive only empty div tags.

but when it's like this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.friend' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    overlayerOn();
    var $uid = $(this).attr("href");
    var $br = $('#board');
    $br.css('display', 'block');
    $('#board').text($uid);
    });
```

It's printing out actual correct value. Why it's not able to pass it? Thank you

Comment: can you provide php script of messages.php

Comment: I edited the question and put info you asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `$uid` contains an href, which is probably a URI of some sort. Encode it before sending it to PHP so it can be properly retrieved from `$_GET`.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.friend' , function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  overlayerOn();
  var $uid = $(this).attr("href");
  var $br = $('#board');
  $br.css('display', 'block');

  // Send the encoded URI to PHP.
  $('#board').load("messages.php?uid=" + encodeURIComponent($uid));
});
```

#### Update

After seeing the PHP posted, I'll just add that when you are passing a value directly from the HTTP request to PHP output, you should escape it against cross-site scripting attacks.

```
$id = $_REQUEST['uid'];
echo "<div id='hovno'>" . htmlspecialchars($id) . "</div>";
```

Comment: My href contain #3 for example, it's every time # + some number

Comment: What I'm trying to do is for now just to receive something in my php script, so so far im just trying to $_REQUEST['uid'].

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your `$uid` in the data-option of .load()?

```
$('#board').load("messages.php", { 'uid': $uid } );
```

Use `$_POST['uid']` in your php-script to receive the data...